# Problems installing Drupal with Xampp and Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, drupal, ubuntu, content-management-system

I am attempting a fresh install of Drupal 6.14 on a Ubuntu 9.10 machine using XAMPP for Linux. I use XAMPP fine with Wordpress and some different frameworks. I am having problems after I download and extract Drupal to my /htdocs/. The following pic shows the errors I get.

[image: Problem installing Drupal with XAMPP]

Comment: People here (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1270884) are having the same problem, with no solution posted.

Comment: Can this question be migrated to serverfault?

Comment: @Bua: Right now it needs two more votes for 'close, as belongs to superuser.com'. Alternatively, you can flag it for 'Requires Moderator attention' and put your migration request in the explanation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is a combination of using php5.3 and having warn levels too high. php is outputting warnings which means that Drupal can't change the header information.

If you are on Ubuntu why would you not just use the standard php and mysql?

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I go about that?

Comment: apt-get will do the trick, there is an old howto here http://www.theatons.com/ubuntu-install-php5-mysql-apache2-ssl-pdo-pdo_mysql

Comment: There is even an entire group devoted to the use of drupal with ubuntu. It is called (very imaginatively!) DRUBUNTU. How-to's on how to configure the server are provided too. http://groups.drupal.org/drubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Drupal is not compatible with PHP 5.3 you should download an older xampp that includes PHP version less than 5.3

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to display deprecated function messages by altering /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini error_reporting directive to:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED | E_STRICT
```